# Automake/autotools and using "--dry-run" and "--always-make" for make

Tags: gnu-make, autotools, autoconf

I stumbled upon an issue when I recently switched to VSCode as editor.

I have several projects that have a full (medium-complex+) autotool
setup and they all work fine. However I discovered that the makefile plugin for VSCode in order to initialize itself (and finding all dependencies and targets) starts by running

```
make --dry-run --always-make
```

as first time initialization. This throws the makefile (or actually the
re-config) into an endless loop re-running "configure" (since the targets are never resolved to disk).

I have also confirmed this behavior with the smallest possible autoconf/automake
setup. I can also kind-of understand why this happens (and it seems make
have an internal way to discover this exact situation with the special
variable MAKE_RESTARTS that could possible be used to detect a cyclic
behavior)

Is there a known best-practice workaround ? or is it even a reasonable expectations that these two options in combination should work? (Good to have a second opinion before I go down the rabbit-hole of reminding myself of all the details I forgot about the magical land of autotools)?

Comment: Possibly this is a bug in your version of `make`.  I do not reproduce it with GNU `make` 4.0.

Comment: Note also that it is entirely plausible that in an Autotools project, that combination of `make` options causes `configure` to run.  It does for me in practice. But in that case it *does* update the makefile, or at least tries to do.  The potential bug here is that when `make` restarts, it still considers the makefile out of date on account of the `--always-make` option.  This is not directly related to the Autotools.  In a `make` that has such an issue, it should be possible to reproduce it with any makefile that has a rule for remaking itself.

Comment: I use make 4.2.1. I just reproduced the problem by trying to rebuild make itself. It will also go into an endless loop trying to reconfigure itself with the combination of these options. So it is not just my setup that has this problem. To me it seems that the combination of the options are mutually exclusive

Comment: The options are not mutually exclusive.  In fact, it seems unlikely that `--dry-run` has anything to do with the problem.  The issue is surely with makefiles that have rules to re-make themselves (as Automake-based makefiles do), combined with `--always-make`.  There may be other factors in play, too -- for instance, there seems to be some dependency on the build or version of `make`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Tried it with GNU make 4.3 as well. Using only "--always-make" as option is enough to through an autotools generated makefile into an endless loop. I can also reproduce similar problem with both GNU make 4.0 and 4.1 (when trying to rebuild make itself)

Answer (score 2):

#### The problem

The infinite loop when dry-running autoconf projects is due to `GNU Make`'s documented behaviour. It's not a bug, or version-specific behaviour:

1. GNU Make remakes files makefiles unconditionally (defined as files it reads rules from, eg, given a statement "include blah.inc", the file `blah.inc` is a "makefile"). [Remaking Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html) says "*`--dry-run` does not prevent updating of makefiles, because an out-of-date makefile would result in the wrong output for other targets*"
2. Automake creates rules for updating the Makefile when `Makefile.am` changes, and when `configure.ac` changes.
3. In recursive builds, when make spawns a sub-make process, it does not pass "`--assume-old`" arguments to child make via the `MAKEFLAGS` mechanism. This is described in [Communicating Options to a Sub-make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html)

Together, these three behaviours guarantee that an autoconf+automake project will end up in an infinite loop when "`--dry-run`" as the vscode "Makefile Tools" extension does by default when projects are loaded.

#### Solution

The solution is to change the command line options as follows (`settings.json` excerpt):

```json
"makefile.dryrunSwitches": [
        "--always-make",
        "--print-directory",
        "--dry-run",
        "--assume-old=Makefile",
        "Makefile",
        "all",
        "AM_MAKEFLAGS=--assume-old=Makefile Makefile"
],
```

If using the GUI, each of these strings must appear on one line. Specifically, `AM_MAKEFLAGS=--assume-old=Makefile Makefile` is one argument. In a bash command line, this would be quoted like `AM_MAKEFLAGS="--assume-old=Makefile Makefile"`

#### Explanation

The `--assume-old=Makefile` means the file named 'Makefile', which is also a target, will not be considered for remake, in spite of `--always-make`, per [Avoiding Compilation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Avoiding-Compilation.html).

Since the file `Makefile` is also a file (ie, used to read rules from), it would be re-made in spite of "--dry-run". This behaviour is overriden by specifying `Makefile` as a target, in addition to `all`, as documented in [Remaking Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html): "*on occasion you might actually wish to prevent updating of even the makefiles. You can do this by specifying the makefiles as goals in the command line as well as specifying them as makefiles. When the makefile name is specified explicitly as a goal, the options ‘-t’ and so on do apply to them.*"

Since on recursive builds the `--assume-old` argument would not be passed to the sub-make via make's own `MAKEFLAGS` environment variable mechanism, the `AM_MAKEFLAGS` variable is used to perform override this behaviour. This works because automake projects add the value of this variable on every make invocation.

**Note 1.** If your project defines the `AM_MAKEFLAGS` variable in Makefile.am, you'll need to adjust it to include the needed `--assume-old` incantation. One way would be:

```
AM_MAKEFLAGS="--project-specific-make-flags $(DRYRUN_MAKEFLAGS)"
```

Then, use use `DRYRUN_MAKEFLAGS="--assume-old=Makefile Makefile"` in `settings.json`.

**Note 2.** Which of the `settings.json` files you put the "makefile.dryrunSwitches" settings matters. If you work on autoconf as well as cmake projects, you might want it in each project's `settings.json`. I have it set at the user level, as I work on very few cmake projects, and then I can override in at the project level.

**Note 3.** Arguably, the default setting for `makefile.dryrunSwitches` in the Makefile Tools extension is wrong, and the extension can be considered buggy. However, it does not claim to be compatible with automake, so fixing this would require adding automake compatibility. See my [pull request #500](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-makefile-tools/pull/500)